# How do you declare an array using an initializer list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist

**creating the array would be this:**

```
final int SIZE = 15, MULTIPLE = 10;
```

`int [] list = new int [SIZE];`

**however, would this be the correct way to initialize the array?**

```
for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++)
      list [index] = index * MULTIPLE;
```

Comment: Yes, except that this will start with `0` for `list[0]`, which I'm not sure is correct for you.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is strange (standard js). You can initialise a new array with `new Array(10)` which creates a new array with a length of 10 but with empty values. So  you can't iterate or map over the array or work with the values.

There is a `.fill` function on array, if you use this in combination with Array(10) this creates an array of some length with values.

Then you can use `for` or the more javascript idiomatic why `map` to map the index value with your multiplier.

```js
const SIZE = 15, MULTIPLE = 10;
const tmpArray = new Array(SIZE)
const initalArray = tmpArray.fill(0).map((value, i) => (i * MULTIPLE))

console.log(initalArray)
```